# How to plot Histogram and Dot diagrams and save to picture in C++

Tags: c++, png, plot, diagram

I have tested a lot of different C++ library's(SIGL, PLplot, libharu and some other randoms) for plotting but i have not found anyone that suites my need or is working properly.

My need is to create a histogram and a dot diagram using 100 000 - 1000 000 values from a 2 dimensional matrix. Save it to a picture png or jpeg format preferred. 
I use Visual studio 2010 and have a Windows XP operating system.
I need to be able to use C++ and I would prefer if there was some good documentation on the library too.

Note is that I do not want to use Matlab, since that is what I am replacing.

Love
Pewdut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely sympathize with not wanting to use Matlab.  If it's just the non-free aspect you don't like, then Octave is a good alternative, it is a fairly complete Matlab clone escept for the gui-building facilities.

I use the [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (very highly recommended) for creating histograms, it has library functions for doing this (1- and 2-D), and its data structures (matrix, vector) can handle at least 300,000 x 64 doubles (This is as high as I've gone on a 2GB RAM machine, naturally more RAM = more capacity, probably).  It is very fast.  For graphing, I use Qt, and the [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/histogramscreenshots.html) toolbox within it has specific functions for making histograms.  The example doesn't show it but axis labels and legends are straightforward.  Qt is relatively heavyweight, but superb imo.

Edit: The author of Qwt gives a list of the classes/functions that support exporting plots, [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/47264-Qwt-amp-save-as-image?highlight=qwt%20plot%20jpg).

Comment: I actually went with a much easier way, I will make the plotting in C# using MSChart. It got great charts and are very well documented. And bonus on not being forced to use it with any other components in my opinion. And I will then call the C# code from my C++ program.